# How to assign the property of one array of objects to another array of strings?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase-storage, for-in-loop

I got an array of items and would like to know if there is an easier way to assign each property `item.fullPath` to another array. Right now I am using a `for in` loop.

```
var items: Array<String> = []
        for item in storageListResult.items {
            items.append(item.fullPath)
        }
```

But is there something similar to this:

```
let items = storageListResult.items[].fullPath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using map

```
let items = storageListResult.items.map{$0.fullPath}
```

And in swift 5.2 you can also do it like

```
let items = storageListResult.items.map(\.fullPath)
```

Comment: I added `.items` to make it `let items = storageListResult.items.map{$0.fullPath}` and it works perfect! I suggested the edit. Thank!